# Can somebody help me understand node.js and how & why I might use it with a framework like rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

I'm trying to write a scalable interactive chat application for an existing high traffic website. It needs to be scalable on day 1, and chat's concurrency and multi-broadcast issues make it a tricky thing to scale.

My initial plan was to write the whole thing in rails and refactor the chat server into erlang later.

Although I am an experienced PHP dev and sysadmin, both node.js and RoR are new and extremely alien technologies to me, so I could use a little help understanding the core concepts and applications in this scenario. With so many new technologies, it is hard to understand them all.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I recommend you review http://ajaxim.com/. The software is a pre-packaged version of what you want that relies on Node JS (far easier than rolling your own).

If you still want to write something yourself and have no experience with either technology, I recommend you review some introductory materials:

[Node JS](http://peepcode.com/products/nodejs-i) and [Rails](http://peepcode.com/products/meet-rails-3-i)

The two sources are not free but will give you a quick one hour crash course on each technology.

Comment: Thanks for that. Actually I had seen the 3 branch of ajaxim, but unfortunately it does not allow for chat rooms. I'm trying to get towards something more like IRC, but with a few bells and whistles.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at http://pusherapp.com ! This is if you want to implement a chat app right away.

If on the other hand, you want to implement one all by yourself, Node.js + Socket.io is your best bet. However, if you want chat rooms and stuff, have a look at this:

http://github.com/shripadk/express-juggernaut-demo

This demo app uses Express.JS framework and Juggernaut 2.

I would suggest going for only Node.js if you are building apps that require high concurrency. Its fairly easy to implement a chat room using Node.js compared to other server-side languages (mainly thanks to modules like socket.io). The event-driven architecture of Node.js makes it really easy to implement such stuff. The only catch with Node is that you have to think everything asynchronous! If you are good at Javascript then Node.js should be easy to learn.